# How to enable Salesforce1 lightning app builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am working on salesforce 1 lightning platform.I am using developer org. I want to enable lightning app builder tool in my org, but it is in pilot. I read one of the in which it is mentioned that to enable app builder option you have to raise a case.

But as it is a developer org, i do not have access to open case option in salesforce support. What will be the other option to enable app builder?

also want to know about salesforce support email id, so that i can personally send email to them.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a StackExchange question, and would be better suited to be on the Success Community site.  However, THIS is the link to the Developer.salesforce.com post   https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add lightning app builder in your org.

Firstly contact to support team of salesforce on this no **000800016000**

Note down your case no and send you an email on registered email id on you org regarding case no .after that you have to send an email with your org id.

Ones they acknowledge your mail they will send you agreement paper ,that you have to sign the agreement paper and send back to the pilot of your case.

after the week you can confirmation mail by support team and used chatter option for your case and issues on lightning app activation.

Theses are step I followed for activating the lightning app builder in my org and successfully add this use full technology in my org .

Hope you help this step,just follow above steps.

Answer (score 2):

[Get New Lightning Org](http://bit.ly/lightning-org)

You can use the link above to create new Developer Environment with Lightning App Builder enabled. It has all lightning components enabled.

Once you register go to "Setup" -> "Build" -> "Lightning App Builder"

Enjoy building Lightning Apps. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lightning app builder is currently in pilot , it will be enabled in your company sandboxes only if your company is part of the pilot.
You can raise a support ticket and follow up with the product manager to include your box as part of the pilot program.